# How can I show custom fields (formula) in the Multi-Line Layout for Opp Products

Tags: community, administration, opportunity-lineitem

[image]I have a formula field on Opportunity Product which i need to show on the Opportunity product Mulitline Edit page. I cant seem to get the formulafield on the available Fields List.

I understand that we cant see a formula field on edit or new records and hence maybe these fields are not visible. Am i correct ?

Is there any other way we could get it displayed?

PricebookEntry.Product2.Booking_Fee_del__c

Custom field is Booking Fee???

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so first you create your custom formula field by going to Customize>Opportunities>Opportunity Products>Fields.

Now that the field is created go to the opportunity page layout: Customize>Opportunities>Page Layouts.

Go down to the Product Related List and click on the small wrench to configure the related list.  From the available fields select your new formula field.  Save your page layout and you should see it on the opportunity page.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a pretty old answer but: That reply does not answer the question. She/he wants the field on the Opportunity product Mulitline Edit page. Not the related list on Opportunity page. It appears that formula fields are not supported there. The only other option may be to create a non-formula field (eg text, picklist, number etc) and then use a record triggered flow to populate it every time a product is created or edited.